# filtering on angularJS fails

Tags: angularjs

My code is like this

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>Name only
        <br />
        <table id="searchObjResults">
            <tr>
                <th>Search</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends  | filter:search:strict  | limitTo:1">
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="search.name" />
                </td>
                <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
                <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</body>


    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'
    }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
    }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'
    }, {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }, {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'
    }, {
        name: 'Juliette',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }];

}]);
```

When I run this it does not works, I know I can change the position of that search textbox and make this work. But for various reasons I can't do it in my project. is there any other way to achieve what I want?

**http://jsfiddle.net/v2xqmkwx/8/**

Comment: do u want to filter the rwo data by name or do u want to filter the whole table by name ?

Comment: This is totally wrong ! What if the user types in something that is not in your friends list, then there is not way to get back the grid coz the text field containing the textbox will also be now hidden

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha i want to filter whole table and show only first result

Comment: @Yasser what I want is simply, user can type any name from the list and most matching single row to be bound at the result. I don't want users to add something that is not in my data list. Its just auto lookup, that i want

Comment: You have a chicken and egg problem here: for the filter box to appear, the row containing the filter box must be accepted by the filter, but you can only enter a filter is the filter box is displayed. That makes no sense.

Comment: @JBNizet I am ready to alter my entire code if it got wrong concept. what I want is just auto look up. when user enters some thing and that matches the data I have in hand I want to fill the rmaining of row with that data.

Comment: So, you want a table with a single row, containing a filter in the first cell of this unique row, and the properties of the first object matching the filter in the following cells? Is that right? Why use a table for a single row?

Comment: @JBNizet You are correct. I am okay with altering table with something else. But I need all of em in single row, That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
    <table id="searchObjResults">
        <tr>
            <th>Search</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="search.name" ng-change="findFriend(search)"/>
            </td>
            <td>{{ firstFriendFound.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ firstFriendFound.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And in the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$filter', '$scope', function ($http, $filter, $scope) {

    $scope.findFriend = function(search) {
        var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.friends, search);
        $scope.firstFriendFound = filtered.length > 0 ? filtered[0] : null;
    };
```

Comment: I have made a try and failed, Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Edited: Misunderstood the question

You can actually do this by repeating two td element in the same row using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.

Here is the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/lookman/rkwoj70k/2/)

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div>Search by all

    <br />
    <table id="searchObjResults">
        <tr>
             <th>Search</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>

        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td><input ng-model="searchText" /></td>
            <td ng-repeat-start="friendObj in friends  | filter:searchText  | limitTo:1">{{friendObj.name}}</td>

               <td ng-repeat-end="friendObj in friends  | filter:searchText  | limitTo:1">{{friendObj.phone}}</td>

        </tr>


    </table>
</div>
<div>

</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
$scope.friends = [{
    name: 'John',
    phone: '555-1276'
}, {
    name: 'Mary',
    phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
}, {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '555-4321'
}, {
    name: 'Adam',
    phone: '555-5678'
}, {
    name: 'Julie',
    phone: '555-8765'
}, {
    name: 'Juliette',
    phone: '555-5678'
}];


$scope.submitForm = function (theData) {
    console.log('FriendObj:' + theData);
};

}]);
```

Comment: @athul Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: I have already told in my question that I can't change the position of textbox. If that doesn't make sense, I think I am going in a wrong direction may be filter directive is not the right tool for the job

Comment: @Athul I fixed my answer. I hope now it helps.

Comment: @Athul This actually filter the name and also the phone number